# How to parse string into datetime format

Tags: c#

I want to parse a date-time string into a `DateTime` data type.

The format of the string is like `08/10/2013 09:49 PM`, and I want it to go to the form `2013-10-08 21:49:05.6500000`

The following is my code but it's not working.

```
public static DateTime ConvertDateTime(String arg_dateTime)
{
    try
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(arg_dateTime, 
            "dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s fff", 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: delete the ':s' from the parsing template

Comment: Do you believe that "08/10/2013 09:49 PM" matches the format "dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s fff"? Look at it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Your format string doesn't match your input data. Try a format string of `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"`, and see the [custom date and time format documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more information.

Note that rather than catching an exception if it fails, you should use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) and check the return value. Or if a failure here represents a big failure, just use `ParseExact` and don't catch the exception. Do you *really* want to default to `DateTime.Now`? It seems unlikely to me. You should strongly consider just letting the exception propagate up.

Also, your method doesn't return a particular format - it returns a `DateTime`. That doesn't know anything about a format - if you want to convert the value to a specific format, you should do so specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you need to use `ParseExact` only?

Why not `Parse` ?

```
string arg_dateTime = "2013-10-08 21:49:05.6500000";
var dt =  DateTime.Parse(arg_dateTime, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);//this works
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/V0vHLR)

Comment: The input string is `08/10/2013 09:49 PM`, but it should still work.

Comment: What I meant was that you are using the output format as the input for your example.